# Is there a way to add a background image to a flutter app widescale?

Tags: flutter, dart, background-image, screen

I want to add an image as a background to all of my screens in the app built with Flutter. Is there any possible way of adding such a background image since there are no properties provided in Flutter's ThemeData class?

Comment: This is how I would approach this, I would create a parent page/container/scaffold like widget that will hold all the screens. Then the incoming screens will only begin as a column or a container not as a scaffold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to achieve that is to create a custom widget that you could call `ScaffoldImage` and which will contain the following code

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/images/your_background.png"),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: Container() //Your child here
    )
);
```